# Google Closure - goog.require could not find goog.ui.AutoComplete

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

After updating to revision 2156 of the Google Closure Library, `goog.require()` fails to find `goog.ui.AutoComplete`.

```
svn update 
At revision 2156.
```

**Error Message**

```
goog.require could not find: goog.ui.AutoComplete.Remote base.js:333
Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: goog.ui.AutoComplete.Remote
```

Everything is fine except for `goog.ui.AutoComplete`. This error has only occurred since I updated Google Closure Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure Library [revision r2132](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/detail?r=2132) dated August 30, 2012 has the following log message:

> Remove all closure/ui/autocomplete code. This is the last step of a big
>   goog.ui.AutoComplete rename/cleanup
>
> If this change BREAKS YOU - first of all, SORRY!

The new package for autocomplete is `goog.ui.ac`, so your require statements need to be updated:

```
goog.require('goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete');
```

Comment: You sir AWESOME! I spent 6hours yesterday!! Thanks a lot!